# Error when starting Bluebinder service

Tags: kali-linux, android

[image]

Earlier error I was getting:

[image]

```
Hit:1 http://kali.download/kali kali-rolling InRelease                            
Reading package lists... Done          
Building dependency tree... Done        
Reading state information... Done    
Note, selecting 'libglib2.0-dev' for glob 'libglib2.0*-dev'                        
E: Unable to locate package python3-bleuzlibbluetooth-dev                        
fatal: destination path '/root/carwhisperer' already exists and is not an empty directory.                                
gcc  carwhisperer.c -o carwhisperer -lbluetooth
carwhisperer.c:46:10: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory  
46 | #include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  compilation terminated.                
make: *** [Makefile:9: carwhisperer] Error 1                                      
fatal: destination path '/root/bt_audit' already exists and is not an empty directory.                                      
gcc psm_scan.c -o psm_scan -lbluetooth  
psm_scan.c:60:10: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory      
60 | #include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:4: psm_scan] Error 1  cp: cannot stat 'rfcomm_scan': No such file or directory
fatal: destination path '/root/libglibutil' already exists and is not an empty directory.
make: pkg-config: No such file or directory
cc -c -fPIC   -Wall -Iinclude -MMD -MP  -g -DDEBUG -MT"build/debug/gutil_history.o" -MF"build/debug/gutil_history.d" src/gutil_history.c -o build/debug/gutil_history.o
In file included from include/gutil_history.h:36,
                 from src/gutil_history.c:33:
include/gutil_types.h:36:10: fatal error:glib.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include <glib.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:180: build/debug/gutil_history.o] Error 1
fatal: destination path '/root/libgbinder' already exists and is not an empty directory.
make: pkg-config: No such file or directory
cc -c -fPIC   -Wall -Wstrict-aliasing -Wunused-result -Iinclude -MMD -MP  -g -DDEBUG -MT"build/debug/gbinder_bridge.o" -MF"build/debug/gbinder_bridge.d" src/gbinder_bridge.c -o build/debug/gbinder_bridge.o
In file included from include/gbinder_local_request.h:36,
                 from src/gbinder_bridge.c:33:
include/gbinder_types.h:36:10: fatal error: gutil_types.h: No such file or directory
   36 | #include <gutil_types.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:264: build/debug/gbinder_bridge.o] Error 1
fatal: destination path '/root/bluebinder' already exists and is not an empty directory.
cc  -Wall -flto bluebinder.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs libgbinder glib-2.0 libsystemd` -DUSE_SYSTEMD=1 -o bluebinder
/bin/sh: 1: pkg-config: not found
bluebinder.c:41:10: fatal error: bluetooth/bluetooth.h: No such file or directory
   41 | #include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [Makefile:14: bluebinder] Error 1
BadBT is installed!
Bluetooth service is patched!
Everything is installed!

Press any key to continue...
```

Now, Iam getting:

[image]

```
┌──(root㉿kali)-[/]
└─# echo -ne "\033]0;BT Arsenal Setup\007" && clear;if [[ -f /usr/bin/hciconfig && -f /usr/bin/l2ping && -f /usr/bin/fang && -f /usr/bin/blueranger &&-f /usr/bin/bluelog && -f /usr/bin/sdptool && -f /usr/bin/spooftooph && -f /usr/bin/sox && -f /usr/include/bluetooth/bluetooth.h ]];then echo 'All packages are installed!'; else apt-get update && apt-get install bluetooth bluez bluez-tools bluez-obexd libbluetooth3 sox spooftooph libglib2.0*-dev libsystemd-dev python3-dbus python3-bleuzlibbluetooth-dev redfang bluelog blueranger -y;fi;if [[ -f /usr/bin/carwhisperer && -f /usr/bin/rfcomm_scan ]];then echo 'All scripts are installed!'; else git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/carwhisperer-0.2 /root/carwhisperer;cd /root/carwhisperer;make && make install;git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/bt_audit /root/bt_audit;cd /root/bt_audit/src;make;cp rfcomm_scan /usr/bin/;fi;if [[ -f /usr/lib/libglibutil.so ]]; then echo 'Libglibutil is installed!'; else git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/libglibutil /root/libglibutil;cd /root/libglibutil;make && make install-dev;fi;if [[ -f /usr/lib/libgbinder.so ]]; then echo 'Libgbinder is installed!'; else git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/libgbinder /root/libgbinder;cd /root/libgbinder;make && make install-dev;fi;if [[ -f /usr/sbin/bluebinder ]]; then echo 'Bluebinder is installed!'; else git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/bluebinder /root/bluebinder;cd /root/bluebinder;make && make install;fi;if [[ -f /root/badbt/btk_server.py ]]; then echo 'BadBT is installed!'; else git clone https://github.com/yesimxev/badbt /root/badbt && cp /root/badbt/org.thanhle.btkbservice.conf /etc/dbus-1/system.d/;fi;if [[ ! "`grep 'noplugin=input' /etc/init.d/bluetooth`" == "" ]]; then echo 'Bluetooth service is patched!'; else echo 'Patching Bluetooth service..' && sed -i -e 's/# NOPLUGIN_OPTION=.*/NOPLUGIN_OPTION="--noplugin=input"/g' /etc/init.d/bluetooth;fi; echo 'Everything is installed!' && echo '
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `then'

┌──(root㉿kali)-[/]
└─# Press any key to continue...' && read -s -n 1 && exit
>
```

Comment: Kali is for advanced security researchers only. If you cannot work out what is wrong & how to fix it, then Kali is not for you. Install a more mainstream distro. Any tools you need can be run easily on them. Kali is not named after the hindu god. I really do with they would change the name as that would stop an awful lot of people needlessly installing it.